# How to configure ipmi on sun fire x2100

Tags: solaris, ipmi

I've recently been asked to look after a Sun Fire X2100 running Solaris 10, which is sitting in a rack on the other side of the world from me. It's running fine at present, but the hosts don't have remote console access, and there's no response from the LOM web gui when the system is down.

Accordingly, I'd like to set up ipmi for out-of-band access so I can get sol going. I'm new to ipmi, and need to a) know how to config it on the box to work over the network, and b) know any further config to make sol work. Pointers/advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have a pile (well, a stack) of X2200-M2s which are similar to your X2100.

I would start by downloading all the documentation for the X2100 from <strike>Sun</strike> Oracle, here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19121-01/sf.x2100/index.html

If you have a X2100-M2, the documentation is here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19121-01/sf.x2100m2/index.html

The -M2 page includes a Embedded Lights Out Manager Administration Guide which is almost certainly where you want to look.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to first check to see if you even have IPMI.

If you have an x2100, the version prior to the M2, you will not have IPMI unless you purchased an add-on Service Processor:

http://sunsolve.sun.com/handbook_pub/validateUser.do?target=Systems/SunFireX2100/components

Which is an option card which mounts on top of the DVD bay.

Not sure about Solaris, but if you have linux installed try doing a:

```
dmidecode | grep -i ipmi
```

And see if you get anything back.